# How to keep NSTableViewDataSource safe during modifications

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I've got an `NSTableViewDataSource`/`...Delegate` backed by an array in my controller. Now, from time to time I'm going to update the array, but I'd like to make sure this doesn't happen while the UI is possibly refreshing what's displayed.

The trivial part is locking the list itself, so it doesn't get change while drawing each cell. But how do I lock it for the whole update cycle? (i.e. from getting the number of rows to finishing the current screen draw) Are there any pre/post update hooks I can use, or are there better ways to approach it?

Comment: It's best to simply perform modifications on the main queue. This is the only way you can really be sure the table view's internal cache won't get out of sync with your data source.

Comment: Does it prevent updates between cell draws? For example: got 3 rows, "now draw row 1", "now draw row 2", update! got 2 rows, "now draw row 3"?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean. When cells are rendered depends on when they are needed, such as if the user is scrolling.

Comment: To rephrase, the specific question is: if I schedule something on the main queue with `DispatchQueue.main.async`, is there a chance that it happens between the UI requesting the number of rows and requesting the cell view of a given row.

Comment: The UI will only request the number of rows when you tell it that the number has changed. As long as your actual model update is partnered with an `insertRowsAtIndexes:` (or whatever updates are needed), then there is no risk of the UI requesting cells for rows which no longer exist in your model.